# create muli-splits of datasets using one command of train_test_split

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

- My dataset has `42000` rows
- I need to divide the dataset into `training, cross-validation and test` sets with splits of `60%, 20% and 20%`. This is as per the advice of Professor Andrew Ng in his ml-class lecture.
- I realized that scikit-learn has a method [train_test_split](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html#sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split) to do this. But I can not make it work so that I get the splits as `0.6, 0.2, 0.2` in one liner command

What I do is

```
# split data into training, cv and test sets
from sklearn import cross_validation
train, intermediate_set = cross_validation.train_test_split(input_set, train_size=0.6, test_size=0.4)
cv, test = cross_validation.train_test_split(intermediate_set, train_size=0.5, test_size=0.5)


# preparing the training dataset
print 'training shape(Tuple of array dimensions) = ', train.shape
print 'training dimension(Number of array dimensions) = ', train.ndim
print 'cv shape(Tuple of array dimensions) = ', cv.shape
print 'cv dimension(Number of array dimensions) = ', cv.ndim
print 'test shape(Tuple of array dimensions) = ', test.shape
print 'test dimension(Number of array dimensions) = ', test.ndim
```

and gets me the result of

```
training shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (25200, 785)
training dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  2
cv shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (8400, 785)
cv dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  2
test shape(Tuple of array dimensions) =  (8400, 785)
test dimension(Number of array dimensions) =  2
features shape =  (25200, 784)
labels shape =  (25200,)
```

How can I make this work in one command?

Comment: You can't do this in a one-liner with current scikit-learn, so your way is currently the best option. Feel free to submit a patch.

Comment: I am actually wondering why would you need such split? In data mining usual practices are to do cross-validation OR do a split of input data into test/train data. These two aproaches are usually not combined. How will you use these data to train your classifier?

Answer (score 1):

Read the source code of [train_test_split](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L1264) and its companion class [ShuffleSplit](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cross_validation.py#L707) and adapt it to your use case. It's not a big function, it should not be very complicated.

Comment: BTW: I agree that scikit-learn could offer such a tool by default, either by extending the features of the existing function / class pair or by introducing new ones for this case.

Comment: I am not sure. This is easy enough to do in two lines of numpy - hm maybe a bit more, thinking about it... alright then ;)

Comment: I'd rather advocate the use of cross-validation, though.

Comment: A 3-way split can be useful for cross-validating unsupervised models using consensus / stability-based evaluation criterions.

Also we might want train / validation (early stopping / monitoring) / test (for final evaluation) splits for incremental models that could benefit from early stopping.

Comment: @AndreasMueller: when the function has to handle sparse matrices as well, things get complicated...